# Why does vuex not fill my v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component with a veutify datatable in it. This is connected to my vuex store, and upon loading the component it should fill the table with data.

Upon loading I can see the data being fetched and getting in the store OK, but the table does not update. Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Table-component:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :items="listOfUsers" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.userid }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.firstname }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.lastname }}</td>
      <td >{{ props.item.mobilenumber }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'usertable',
  computed: {
    listOfUsers () {
      return this.$store.state.users.userLIst
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Calling page:

```
<template>
    <UserTable></UserTable>
</template>

<script>
import { FETCH_USER_LIST } from '../store/actions.type'

import UserTable from './UserTable.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Users',
  components: {
    UserTable
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch(FETCH_USER_LIST)
  }
}
</script>
```

Not sure what im doing wrong since I can see the data, but the table does not update.

The stores are registerid in the index like this:

```
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth,
    users
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you register the store in the root component? Is `return this.$store.state.users.userLIst` really correct? `userLIst` (capital `I`)?

Comment: Hi, updated question with registering code. I add these like that. I can see the data in the store as well, its just not updating to the model-binding.

Comment: How about the capital `I` in `userLIst`? Not a typo? Also, don't you have any other root component? a `new Vue({ ... }` one?

Comment: When I changed to correct sspelling "userList" I got a ton of errors in console and found the error. I was setting the store to a object instead of an array. It fixed it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Aw, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the datatable expected an array but got an object. Nothing was logged in console because I had missed a capital letter.